# No configure file to make static version of qt

Tags: c++, qt, deployment

I want to deploy my qt program using static linking following this documentation:
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/linux-deployment.html

When I try the command "./configure -static -prefix /usr/bin", I get an error:
"bash: ./configure: No such file or directory"

I understand that happens because there is no configure file. In the documentation it says "/path/to/Qt". /usr/bin seems to be the path where qt is installed.

Why is it not working? Am I in the wrong directory?

I wrote the application in C++ using the Qt Creator on a Raspberry Pi 2 with Raspbian Jessie. I want to deploy it so I can use it on another Raspberry that has minimal functionality without desktop-gui or qtcreator installed. I am using Raspbian Jessie Lite on that one.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem after installing qt creator `5.10`.

The qt directory does not have a configure file. However, the source directory for qt does.

In my installation, that is:

```
~/qt/5.10.1/Src
```

If you cd into that directory, you can run the `./configure` command. At least i am able to.